# How to retrieve all the values form the mapping?

Tags: arrays, mapping, authentication

Yield farming. Unaudited food token. Anon founder. Crazy APR%. Of course,  if it is  ***"too good to be true"*** it probably is...

I would like to ***"don't trust, verify"*** and verify who is authorized:

```
contract Authorizable is Ownable {

    mapping(address => bool) public authorized;

    modifier onlyAuthorized() {
        require(authorized[msg.sender] || owner() == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function addAuthorized(address _toAdd) onlyOwner public {
        authorized[_toAdd] = true;
    }

    function removeAuthorized(address _toRemove) onlyOwner public {
        require(_toRemove != msg.sender);
        authorized[_toRemove] = false;
    }

}
```

It is mapping. It is not an array. I cannot iterate. Adding a guy does not emit the event.

Do I need to write some code to analyze every single transaction to the smart contract?

Or maybe there is some tool / technique / quirk / workaround to the rescue?

Comment: If the answer to Q2 is No, then the answer to Q1 is Yes.

Comment: If the answer to Q2 is Yes, then that tool performs exactly what you describe in Q1.

Comment: Thank you @goodvibration  Maybe someone already has a piece of code sitting somewhere?